# Trying to match an exact subset in python

Tags: python, list, set

I'm trying to see if a set in python contains the elements of another set. I've tried to use set comparison but the problem is I need to be able to recognise only an exact match of elements. For example a subset of [3,3] will match a set of [3,1,2] when I want it to only match to [3,3,1], or any set variant with two threes.

I am iterating through all possible variants of a 3 element set using numbers 0-4, trying to see which ones contain the [3,3] set. Should I be using sets or is it better to use a list? Any ideas on how to do this?

Cheers

Comment: by definition `[3,3]` is not a set, since sets do not contain duplicates.

Comment: @roippi I was trying to apply the Socratic method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method), but never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sets cannot contain duplicate elements. you can use a list or a dict where the value for the key is the number of times the key occurs in your set.

Something like:

```
d1 = {3:2, 1:1}
d2 = {3:2}
all(d1.get(k,0)-v>=0 for (k,v) in d2.items())
```

Comment: How would I do it using a list?

Comment: I modified my answer. I think a map will be easier to use.
so [3,3,1] is represented by {3:2, 1:1}

Comment: you mean a dictionary not map

Comment: @Hyperboreus, what do you mean they ARE?

Comment: @perreal "are" like in https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by set you mean list, something like this should work (not tested):

```
def contains(superset, subset):
    for elem in set(superset):
        if superset.count(elem) < subset.count(elem):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have duplicates in your sets (making them really multisets or "bags", rather than proper sets), you should use `collections.Counter`. It supports set operations (`&`, `+`, `-`) with appropriate multiset semantics.

Testing if one multiset `a` is a subset of another multiset `b` can be done with `a == a & b`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter([3,3])
b = Counter([3,1,2])

print(a == a & b) # prints False, since a is not a subset of b
```